# 1つの検索欄で、2つの列に検索を掛けたい

Tags: javascript, html, css

下記ソースには、column-Name、column-Positionの検索入力欄があり、それぞれの入力欄はそれぞれの対象列(NameとPosition)に対して検索を掛け、一致した行のみを描画します。
ここで、
この2つの検索欄を1つにし、この１つの検索欄で2つの列(NameとPosition)に対する検索(or検索)が出来るようにしたいのですが方法が分かりません。
ご教授をお願いします。

```js
function filterColumn ( i ) {
    $('#example').DataTable().column( i ).search(
        $('#col'+i+'_filter').val()
    ).draw();
}
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
 
    $('input.column_filter').on( 'keyup click', function () {
        filterColumn( $(this).parents('tr').attr('data-column') );
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table style="width: 67%; margin: 0 auto 2em auto;" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Target</th>
                <th>Search text</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
 
        <tbody>
            <tr id="filter_col1" data-column="0">
                <td>Column - Name</td>
                <td align="center"><input class="column_filter" id="col0_filter" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="filter_col2" data-column="1">
                <td>Column - Position</td>
                <td align="center"><input class="column_filter" id="col1_filter" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
 
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
 
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: 「and検索」「or検索」のどちらかによって回答内容が変わるような気がするので、どちらを想定されているか記載した方が適切な回答が得やすいかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問内容から読み取れない要素がいくつかあるので、ご提示のコードからできるだけ改変せずにやってみます。
こんな感じでいけませんか？

```
//検索欄作成時
$('input.column_filter').on('keyup click', function () {
    filterColumn(1);
    filterColumn(2);
});
```